# Replacing anchor/link in text

Tags: c#, html, regex, string

I'm having issues doing a find / replace type of action in my function, i'm extracting the **< a href="link">anchor** from an article and replacing it with this format: **[link anchor]**  the link and anchor will be dynamic so i can't hard code the values, what i have so far is:

```
    public static string GetAndFixAnchor(string articleBody, string articleWikiCheck) {
        string theString = string.Empty;
        switch (articleWikiCheck) {
            case "id|wpTextbox1":
                StringBuilder newHtml = new StringBuilder(articleBody);
                Regex r = new Regex(@"\<a href=\""([^\""]+)\"">([^<]+)");
                string final = string.Empty;
                foreach (var match in r.Matches(theString).Cast<Match>().OrderByDescending(m => m.Index))
                {
                    string text = match.Groups[2].Value;
                    string newHref = "[" + match.Groups[1].Index + " " + match.Groups[1].Index + "]";
                    newHtml.Remove(match.Groups[1].Index, match.Groups[1].Length);
                    newHtml.Insert(match.Groups[1].Index, newHref);
                }
                theString = newHtml.ToString();
                break;
            default:
                theString = articleBody;
            break;
        }
        Helpers.ReturnMessage(theString);
        return theString;
    }
```

Currently, it just returns the article as it originally is, with the traditional anchor text format: **< a href="link">anchor**

Can anyone see what i have done wrong?

regards

Comment: you want to replace the whole tag, or just the content of the "href" attribute? It's not clear

Comment: The whole tag ideally, swap out the traditional anchor format for this: [link anchorText] is the goal.

Comment: Why regex? It can be done easily with HtmlParser such as AngleSharp, HtmlAgilityPack..

Comment: @colinreedy674 I asked because your groups appear to be targeting bits of the tag, and that's what you're using to set the indexes for removal and inserting. BTW you might want to use "Replace" instead of Remove followed by Replace. Or as Frustrated says, use a DOM parsing library.

Comment: Does your `case "id|wpTextbox1":` trigger at all? Please check. The rest can be easily fixed with `Regex.Replace`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input is HTML, you should consider using a corresponding parser, HtmlAgilityPack being really helpful.

As for the current code, it looks too verbose. You may use a single `Regex.Replace` to perform the search and replace in one pass:

```
public static string GetAndFixAnchor(string articleBody, string articleWikiCheck) {
    if (articleWikiCheck == "id|wpTextbox1")
    {
        return Regex.Replace(articleBody, @"<a\s+href=""([^""]+)"">([^<]+)", "[$1 $2]");
    }
    else
    {
        // Helpers.ReturnMessage(articleBody); // Uncomment if it is necessary
        return articleBody;
    }
}
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3Ca%5Cs%2Bhref%3D%22%28%5B%5E%22%5D%2B%29%22%3E%28%5B%5E%3C%5D%2B%29&i=%3Ca%20href%3D%22link%22%3Eanchor&r=%5B%241%20%242%5D).

The `<a\s+href="([^"]+)">([^<]+)` regex matches `<a`, 1 or more whitespaces, `href="`, then captures into Group 1 any one or more chars other than `"`, then matches `">` and then captures into Group 2 any one or more chars other than `<`.

The `[$1 $2]` replacement replaces the matched text with `[`, Group 1 contents, space, Group 2 contents and a `]`.

Answer (score 1):

*Updated (Corrected regex to support whitespaces and new lines)*

---

You can try this expression

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"<[\s\n]*a[\s\n]*(([^\s]+\s*[ ]*=*[ ]*[\s|\n*]*('|"").*\3)[\s\n]*)*href[ ]*=[ ]*('|"")(?<link>.*)\4[.\n]*>(?<anchor>[\s\S]*?)[\s\n]*<\/[\s\n]*a>");
```

It will match your anchors, even if they are splitted into multiple lines. The reason why it is so long is because it supports empty whitespaces between the tags and their values, and C# does not supports subroutines, so this part `[\s\n]*` has to be repeated multiple times.

You can see a working sample at [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AJoJxX)
You can use it in your example like this.

```
public static string GetAndFixAnchor(string articleBody, string articleWikiCheck) {
    if (articleWikiCheck == "id|wpTextbox1")
    {
        return Regex.Replace(articleBody, 
                             @"<[\s\n]*a[\s\n]*(([^\s]+\s*[ ]*=*[ ]*[\s|\n*]*('|"").*\3)[\s\n]*)*href[ ]*=[ ]*('|"")(?<link>.*)\4[.\n]*>(?<anchor>[\s\S]*?)[\s\n]*<\/[\s\n]*a>",
                             "[${link} ${anchor}]");
    }
    else
    {
        return articleBody;
    }
}
```